# insert variable value to database from another function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller

I need some help in here.

This is my controller:

```
function result_selected_abc_data(){
$this->auth->restrict();
$this->load->model('usermodel');
$this->load->model('productmodel');
$level=$this->session->userdata('level');
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('date1','Tanggal  Di Masukkan','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('date2','Tanggal Belum Di Masukkan','trim|required');
$this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:#FF0000;">','</span>');

if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
$data['parent']=$this->usermodel->get_data_parent_menu($level);
$data['first_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_first_child_menu($level);
$data['second_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_second_child_menu($level);
$data['third_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_third_child_menu($level);
$data['fourth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_fourth_child_menu($level);
$data['fifth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_fifth_child_menu($level);
$data['sixth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_sixth_child_menu($level);
$data['seventh_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_seventh_child_menu($level);
$this->template->display('ABC_select_date',$data);
}else{

$data['selected_date']= array(
          'date1' => $this->input->post('date1'),
          'date2' => $this->input->post('date2')
          );
$date1=$this->input->post('date1');
$date2=$this->input->post('date2');
$data['ABC_report_result']= $this->productmodel->get_ABC_data_based_on_date($date1,$date2);
$this->template->display('ABC_select_data_result',$data);
    }
}
```

I want to insert $data['ABC_report_result'] value to database in another fuction let say save abc():

```
function save_abc(){

 **what should I make in here so I can get $data['ABC_report_result'] value and save it to database?**

}
```

how can I do it? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller

```
function save_abc(){
$ArrData = array(
     'database_column'=>'value',
     'database_column2'=>'value2',
);
$this->your_model->your_function($ArrData);

}
```

In your model

```
public function your_function($data=''){

        $this->db->insert('your_table',$data);
    }
```

**Update solution**
You can do one thing In your view file save $date values in hidden field and create a button save data that call action save_abc() now you can do

```
function save_abc(){
   $this->load->model('productmodel');
   $date1=$this->input->post('date1'); //data from hidden field
   $date2=$this->input->post('date2'); //data from hidden field
   $result = $this->productmodel->get_ABC_data_based_on_date($date1,$date2);
  $this->your_model->your_save_function($result);

}
```

Comment: I can understand that, but How can i pass the value within $data['ABC_report_result'] variable from function result_selected_abc_data into save_abc function? then save that data into database in save_abc function?

Answer (score 0):

in CodeIgniter your **input** object are globally accessible! so if you need your data in your save_abc, why you are not trying to insert your input->post() method in your target function?

Comment: Because I need to display the data first to user through result_selected_abc_data function. Then user will decide to save the data or not . so that's why I make another function to save the data into the database. I still can't figure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function result_selected_abc_data()
{
    $this->auth->restrict();
    $this->load->model('usermodel');
    $this->load->model('productmodel');
    $level=$this->session->userdata('level');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date1','Tanggal  Di Masukkan','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date2','Tanggal Belum Di Masukkan','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<span style="color:#FF0000;">','</span>');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == false){
        $data['parent']=$this->usermodel->get_data_parent_menu($level);
        $data['first_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_first_child_menu($level);
        $data['second_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_second_child_menu($level);
        $data['third_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_third_child_menu($level);
        $data['fourth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_fourth_child_menu($level);
        $data['fifth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_fifth_child_menu($level);
        $data['sixth_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_sixth_child_menu($level);
        $data['seventh_child'] = $this->usermodel->get_data_seventh_child_menu($level);
        $this->template->display('ABC_select_date',$data);
    }
    else
    {

        $data['selected_date']= array(
                  'date1' => $this->input->post('date1'),
                  'date2' => $this->input->post('date2')
                  );
        $date1=$this->input->post('date1');
        $date2=$this->input->post('date2');
        $data['ABC_report_result']= $this->productmodel->get_ABC_data_based_on_date($date1,$date2);

        $this->productmodel->save_abc_data($data['ABC_report_result']);

        $this->template->display('ABC_select_data_result',$data);
    }
}
```

am i missing something obvious here ?

Comment: it's not right. if I do it like that user cant decide to save data or not. the logic of this process is to display data first to user then user will choose to save or not the data. so that's why I make two function in here. but I still can't figure out how to pass data from first function (display data) to second function(save data).

Comment: yes there are 2 options for you - but first of all i need to know :

since you are talking about user - do you use sessions ?